# Android Studio: testing is slow

Tags: android, testing, emulation

Every time I want to do a quick test of some code, android studio takes 20-40 minutes loading an emulator which then either crashes my laptop or makes it run very slow. Is there any way to just use the system log without loading the whole app, similar to the `System.out.Prinln()` feature in net beans?

Comment: How do u test the functionality without running app ?? one quick fix is to run on real device via use debugging instead of using emulator

Comment: Emulator should not be starting 20 minutes nor crashing your laptop. Try to solve problem with emulator. If problem is unsolvable ( weak hardware or something ) switch to using a real device for debugging.

Comment: Could you add configurations of your laptop pls?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the question is about running your app for quick testing and not about automated tests. But you can learn a lot by trying to adapt writing tests, and they can help you to solve your problem.

1) For code without android dependencies you can write JUnit tests and run those just on JVM to test the code. Bonus: you'll start with creating your testsuite!

2) For code with android dependencies: a) Try to be better in separating platform specific code and internal logic so you will be able to cover more code with unit tests. b) You can use [roboelectric](http://robolectric.org/) and test everything without emulator/device for the rest.